# Which Linux variant to install on VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, debian

Answer to one of my previous post suggested me to use VirtualBox for Sandbox experiments with malware files. I installed VirtualBox and now it demands a bootable CD to install the OS. I want Linux to be installed in it.

I guess Debian or Ubuntu are the most popular variant. I want an ISO image that creates a bootable CD or a single DVD with that Linux variant and should include only the basic installation not much features. It should fit in at least 3 or 3.5 GB.

Which one is more compatible with VirtualBox?

Comment: They're all compatible with VirtualBox. Just pick whichever you're more familiar with, or whichever is smaller. Linux is Linux; it doesn't really matter which distro you choose if you're only going to be using it for testing malware.

Comment: I am not following which ISO to pick. There are so many ISO files here: http://ftp.ru.debian.org/pub/Linux/debian-cd/5.0.7-live/i386/iso-cd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Virtual Box's [Guest OSes documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes), recent versions of Ubuntu, Debian, SUSE, OpenSUSE, Madriva, Mandrake, Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, Xandros, and ArchLinux all work with VM additions. Most of those distros offer downloadable ISO installers. All of these should be equally "compatible" with VirtualBox.

ArchLinux is the simplest, but possibly too simple. Ubuntu is often considered to be the most user-friendly, and is quite easy to install. A base installation will be under your limit of 3.5GB.

Comment: Where is the complete ISO of Ubuntu? I FTP places, I could see many ISO images.

Comment: Did you try just looking on their website? [ubuntu.com](http://ubuntu.com/) > [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download) > Choose a version > Start Download.